# PHP static classes problem

Tags: php, class, static

```
<?php

class jokz {
    static public $val='123';
    static public function xxx() {
        jokz2(self);
    }
}

function jokz2($obj) {
    echo $obj::$val;
}

jokz::xxx();
?>
```

it returns fatal error, cause the class "self" couldn't be found...
so.. how can i make that work?

passing a parameter by reference  in function also don't work

```
function jokz2(&$obj) {
    echo $obj::$val;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no object to pass** (`self` refers to static class). You can pass the name of the class and call it that way (using [call_user_func](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)) or instantiate an object and pass `$this`

Comment: no other ways? the main aim of this code is that classname should not be passed as a static string, it's like the function xxx don't know the classname

Comment: You can try `__CLASS__`. If you're using PHP >= 5.3, you can call `get_called_class`. Otherwise, you can look into debug_backtrace solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/php-get-classname-from-static-call-in-extended-class

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `$this` to use the current object.