# PHP const/static variables not usable in static context by parent class

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance, constants

For some reason (which?), PHP const/static variables defined in a child class are not usable in a static context by the parent class.

Why?

Example 1:

```
class Model{
  function getAll(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . self::DATABASE_TABLE_NAME;
    // ...
  }
}

class Post extends Model{
  const DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = 'post';
}

$p = Post::getAll();
```

When I run that I get:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'DATABASE_TABLE_NAME' on line 3
```

(The row with $query = ...)

Example 2:

```
class Model{
    function getAll(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . self::$DATABASE_TABLE_NAME;
        // ...
    }
}

class Post extends Model{
    static $DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = 'post';
}

$p = Post::getAll();
```

Then I get:

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Model::$DATABASE_TABLE_NAME on line 3
```

(Same row)

Comment: Because `self` refers to the parent, where the constant or static variable isn't defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP5.3 introduced [late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) — that's what you're looking for.

```
class ParentClass {
    public function getAll() {
        var_dump('Get all from ' . static::TABLE_NAME);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    const TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name';
}

$c = new ChildClass();
$c->getAll(); // Get all from my_table_name
```

---

EDIT:

However you should design your classes a little bit different. The above solution relies on language dynamics (you can refer to something (eg. a class constant) that doesn't even exists). In such a simple example everything is fine but in real word cases this leads to producing horrible and hard to maintain code.

It'd be better to force the delivered class (`ChildClass`) to implement some method that returns table name:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
   // getAll function

   abstract protected function getTableName();
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    // You have to implement this method
    protected function getTableName() {
        return 'table name';
    }
}
```

Comment: That is even better than my $class = get_called_class() solution (see below)!

Comment: @MPV: Please read my updated answer - some important note has been added. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:
[How can I get the classname from a static call in an extended PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/php-get-classname-from-static-call-in-extended-class)

Solution:

```
class Model{
    function getAll(){
        $class = get_called_class();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $class::$DATABASE_TABLE_NAME;
        // ...
    }
}

class Post extends Model{
    static $DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = 'post';
}

$p = Post::getAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

There all available.

Under the static context you should be using [late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) so that the code would become:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . static::$DATABASE_TABLE_NAME;
```

i would also advise you to use constants for sanity reasons.

Comment: I fully agree with constants, I just tried with class variables since constants didn't work but the problem persisted even there.