# How to get class name from static child method

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

```
<?php
class MyParent {

    public static function tellSomething() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent {

}

echo MyChild::tellSomething();
```

The code above echos "MyParent". How can i get to name of child class - in this case "MyChild"? If it's possible...

I just simply need to know which child is calling the inherited method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the classname from a static call in an extended PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/how-can-i-get-the-classname-from-a-static-call-in-an-extended-php-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__CLASS__` is a pseudo-constant, that always refers to the class, where it is defined. With [`late-static-binding`](http://php.net/language.oop5.late-static-bindings) the function [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/get-called-class) were introduced, that resolve the classname during runtime.

```
class MyParent {

  public static function tellSomething() {
    return get_called_class();
  }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent {

}

echo MyChild::tellSomething();
```

(as a sidenote: usually methods don't need to know the class on were they are called)

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is called [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), and it was made available in PHP 5.3.