# PHP: Calling a class name using an inherited function from a extended class

Tags: php, class, inheritance

If effect, I have this in progress:

```
    Class Foo {
      $bar = new Bar();
      protected function Spoon() {
         get_class($this);
      }
    }

    Class Bar extended Foo {
       $this::Spoon(); //Should show "Bar", but instead shows "Foo"
    }
```

I want to be able to find "Bar" from Spoon(), but I always get the parent class.
I'm a little lost here. How might I get this code to work properly?

Comment: Can you reformulate the example with a valid PHP program (or snippet)?

Comment: Is `Foo::Spoon()` static or is the function call to it incorrect. It seems that you're mixing the Paamayim Nekudotayim (::) with `$this->`. Also, code can't be executed the body of a function. It needs to be place in one (like a `__construct`or) and then called (or instantiated with `new Bar();`).

Answer (score 1):

`get_class()` returns 'Foo', because since the `Spoon()` method is inherited, it's executed in the `Foo` class.
Using the `__CLASS__` constant instead of `get_class()` should work as you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo parent::Spoon();
```

That will force it to referenced in the context of the parent class (`Foo`). You could also use [`get_parent_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) inside `Bar`:

```
echo get_parent_class('Bar');
```

Comment: @Rijk Yes. My intermittent edits have created one or two. They're gone now.

Answer (score 1):

you can either use the late static binding (php >= 5.3) like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/php-get-classname-from-static-call-in-extended-class/506737#506737).

```
protected function Spoon() {
    get_called_class($this);
}
```

or call the function with

```
$this->Spoon();
```

Comment: I don't believe static is the problem here. The code he posted is just pseudo code I think.