# get parent extends class in php

Tags: php, class, parent, extend

i have the oop php code:

```
class a {
    // with properties and functions
}

class b extends a {
    public function test() {
        echo __CLASS__; // this is b
        // parent::__CLASS__ // error
    }
}

$b = new b();
$b->test();
```

I have a few parent class (normal and abstract) and many child classes. The child classes extend the parent classes. So when I instantiate the child at some point I need to find out what parent I called.

for example the function `b::test()` will return `a`

How can I get (from my code) the class `a` from my class b?

thanks

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/php-get-classname-from-static-call-in-extended-class

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code suggested you used [parent](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php), which in fact is what you need. The issue lies with the magic `__CLASS__` variable.

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) states:

> As of PHP 5 this constant returns the class name as it was declared.

Which is what we need, but as noted in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#69433) on php.net:

> claude noted that `__CLASS__` always contains the class that it is called in, if you would rather have the class that called the method use get_class($this) instead.  However this only works with instances, not when called statically.

If you only are in need of the parent class, theres a function for that aswell. That one is called [get_parent_class](http://php.net/get_parent_class)

Answer (score 17):

You can use `get_parent_class`:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
  public function test() {
    echo get_parent_class();
  }
}

$b = new B;
$b->test(); // A
```

This will also work if `B::test` is static.

NOTE: There is a small difference between using `get_parent_class` without arguments versus passing `$this` as an argument.  If we extend the above example with:

```
class C extends B {}

$c = new C;
$c->test(); // A
```

We get `A` as the parent class (the parent class of B, where the method is called).  If you always want the closest parent for the object you're testing you should use `get_parent_class($this)` instead.

Answer (score 11):

```
class a {
  // with propertie and functions
}

class b extends a {

   public function test() {
      echo get_parent_class($this);
   }
}


$b = new b();
$b->test();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use reflection to do that:

Instead of

```
parent::__CLASS__;
```

use

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass($this);
echo $ref->getParentClass()->getName();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `class_parents` instead. It'll give an array of parents.

```
<?php
class A {}
class B extends A {
}
class C extends B {
    public function test() {
        echo implode(class_parents(__CLASS__),' -> ');
    }
}

$c = new C;
$c->test(); // B -> A
```