# get class name without having an instance of the class in php

Tags: php, reflection

I am looking for following php-function:

```
class foo
{
}

echo get_class_special(foo);  // returns the string 'foo'
```

Has php a function for getting the name of a class without creating an instance of the class?

Comment: How is that an instance of the class?  You didn't call `new`

Comment: Where will you get the class name from? I mean, you're passing `foo` and expect `foo` back, if the class name was `bar` you'd put in `bar` and get `bar` back...

Comment: If you don't have an instance of an object, you can't pass the object to anything. This means you already have to know the class name, in order to instanciate it, which in turn makes your function redundant...

Comment: Wouldn't you have to know the name of the class to run the function in the first place?  I'm sorry, maybe I'm missing something, but I just can't see any practical use for such a thing.

Comment: Oh I get it now, `get_class_special` is a hypothetical function, not a real function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: get classname from static call in extended class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/php-get-classname-from-static-call-in-extended-class)

Comment: @CodeCaster: you want to now my application? If i refactor my source and rename 'foo' to 'bar' I have to change all parts where 'foo' appears. If I forget some then the php-interpreter will throw an exception with my get_class_special()-function, it will not if the classname only appear in a string-constant.

Comment: And you also have underscore underscore CLASS underscore underscore which returns current class name if you use it within a class methods. (this editor won't escape)

Comment: @Repox: In C# I can write 'typeof(foo).Name' to get the string 'foo' without instantiating foo. Maybe there is also a similar way in php.

Comment: @user1027167 You still have to know what 'Foo' is to get anything 'Foo' - both in C# and PHP.

Comment: @Repos: the difference between foo and 'foo' is that the interpreter knows what I mean with foo, it does not know what I mean with 'foo'. It will inform me if I have a typo in foo, it will not for 'foo'. So I prefere writing foo instead of 'foo', if anyhow possible. Now I am using 'get_class(new foo())'. But I hoped that there is a way without new.

Comment: @Repox This is useful with namespaces. Sometimes you have the short class name, but you need to pass it along for some validation which requires the full class name with its namespace. For example, to implement pseudo generics, which don't exits in PHP.

Comment: @Nomæd, this is a four year old question; much has happened since this question - now you can just use `::class` to get what you want. Including the full namespace even though the namespace is imported.

Comment: @Repox unfortunately I am currently limited to v5.4 so I stumbled across this question. Still relevant to some ;)

Comment: @Nomæd there's really no excuse for staying at 5.4. Update your code, change hosting provider, whatever. All the security patches and features you get with 5.5, 5.6 and even 7.0 should be enough to leave 5.4.

Comment: @Repox, it's not a website. It's a GUI for a large security product (although we're slowly dropping PHP and moving to client-side).

Comment: @Nomæd, you do realize the irony of a security product still running on PHP version 5.4, right?

Comment: @Repox, what I do realize is that in the real world, sometimes you have to make do with the tools you're being given, without being able to choose your personally favorite toolset. I also realize that the OP's question has plenty of valid answers, both regarding PHP < 5.5 and for PHP >= 5.5. I think you should also realize that any decent security product has its own internal code tested and double tested for any known vulnerability. Anyway, I think the point is clear, no reason to keep adding more comments to this years old question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

class Foo {
    const NAME = __CLASS__;
    // or
    public static $NAME = __CLASS__;
    // or
    public static function getName() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

Foo::NAME; // Foo
// or
Foo::$NAME; // Foo
// or
Foo::getName(); // Foo

?>
```

Comment: This wont work if class Bar extends Foo. Bar::NAME will return 'Foo'. PHP 5.5 has ::class constant for this purpose. Example: Bar::class

Answer (score 3):

I get the feeling that there is some confusion regarding dynamic typing in PHP: There is no such thing as an object of type `class` in PHP, classes are expressed by their names. So if you write `foo` in your application, you will get a WARNING and that `foo` will be interpreted as the string `'foo'` - even if there is a class by that name.

So if you need to call a static function on a class that is present in a variable, you can do it like this:

```
$class = 'Foo';
$class::staticFuntion(); // will call Foo::staticFunction()
```

This goes even further, you can [reference variables with variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$className = 'Foo';
$ref = 'className';
$$ref::staticFunction(); // will call Foo::staticFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

[As of PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) you can use `foo::class`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017741/235179).

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating static function like

```
class foo {

    public static function myClass() {
         return get_class($this);
    }
}
```

In your code you could use

```
foo::myClass();  //return string 'foo'
```

But here you need to know the name of the class to call it so its somehow redundant. It would make sense if for example you would like to get properties of the class without instantiating it as they my be changing when developing the code.

Comment: this is the way described in the link Merlyn Morgan-Graham gave above. With the difference 'return get_called_class();' instead of 'return get_class($this);'. I think using '$this' is not possible in a static function.

Answer (score 0):

i guess its not possible to get class name without its object. But if your instance has only one class declared then you can get it using.

```
get_declared_classes();
```