# Difference between ::class and get_class

Tags: php

Can you explain the difference between   `get_class($instance)` and `ClassName::class` ?

```
<?php
// PHP 5.5
var_dump(get_class(new Datetime())); // string(8) "DateTime" 
var_dump(Datetime::class); // string(8) "Datetime" with lower t
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Classnames aren't case sentive in PHP.

It seems like `get_class($obj)` returns true classname (in PHP core) and `::class` returns the classname used in user's code.

```
<?php
// PHP 5.5
var_dump(get_class(new DaTeTImE())); // string(8) "DateTime" 
var_dump(DaTeTImE::class);           // string(8) "DaTeTImE"
```

// From PHP Team : 
The '::class' construct is done purely at compile time, based of the apparent classname passed in. It does not check the spelling of the actual class name, or even that the class exist

```
<?php
echo dAtEtImE::class; // Output is "dAtEtImE"
echo ThisDoesNotExist::class; // Output is "ThisDoesNotExist"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another point is get_class takes instance as argument and ::class operate on Class definition directly without initializing any instance. You might want to get the class name without creating instance occasionally.

Comment: To add on to this answer, you *cannot* use `::class` on an instance, while you *can* use `get_class()`. For example if you did `$d = new DateTime()`, you cannot use `$d::class`.

Comment: @AmbientCyan But `::class` can be used on instances as well.

Answer (score -6):

There is no difference, this is just two coding styles.

Comment: Then why `get_class(new Datetime())` is not striclty equal than `Datetime::class`

Comment: Where do you see a difference ?

Comment: Datetime and DateTime with upper T

Comment: @Raphaël Vigée It's possible for them to return strings with different capitalization, which could break your code.