# PHP: A static variant of the magic method __toString()?

Tags: php, static-methods, tostring

I would like to use PHP's `__toString()` method in a static manner, like so:

```
class MyClass {
    public static function __toString() {
        echo 'Hello, I am MyClass!';
    }
}

echo (string) MyClass;
```

Unfortunately though `__toString()` cannot be a static method. It would be great if this was possible though, so my question is: *Is this something reasonable to propose as a feature request to PHP devs? If not, how can we achieve this kind of functionality as closely to what my example describes as realistically possible?*

Comment: Why would you need this? I can't really think of a use case.

Comment: Use case example: In Yii2 all Object-based classes come with a static [*className()*](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-object.html#className()-detail) method. All it does is return the called class string. With a static *__toString()* that method would no longer be required.

Comment: What about `MyClass::class`?

Comment: @tkausl That works in this particular use case yes!

Comment: See also PHPs built-in `get_class` method. https://php.net/get_class

Comment: As mentioned that is not possible in PHP. If you want to call methods statically  then there is the [Overloading methods via the __callStatic() method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic). It is a little clumsy for your purpose though.

Comment: @jornane get_class() needs to be called externally. It is of no use here. And @tkausl, if we still need to append `::class` each time, it's not much of an improvement over `::className()`. @ryan-vincent: Interesting idea. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
echo MyClass::class;
```

Or if you need more control:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function getClass()
    {
        return get_class();
    }
}

echo MyClass::getClass();
```

If you want to have a static class property, you can use this:

```
class MyClass {
    static $name = self::class;
}

echo MyClass::$name;
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017741/5459839).

Comment: Not perfect because we cannot modify the string, but I guess it's as good as it will get.

Comment: Added an alternative which gives more control.

Comment: That's not ideal either because we cannot use it when declaring a class property (eg. ```public $var = MyClass::getClass();```).

Comment: I added a way to use a class property to my answer.