# PHP return the instanceof an object

Tags: php, scripting

I know how to check for the 'instanceof' an object using :

```
function checkInstance($obj) {
    if ($obj instanceof stdClass) {return ('this is a stdClass object');}
    return false;
}   
$x = new stdClass();
echo '<pre>'.print_r($x,2).'</pre>';
echo checkInstance($x);
```

**Outputs:**

```
stdClass Object
(
)
this is a stdClass object
```

However, how do I query an object so that it returns to me its instance?

e.g.

```
function getInstance($obj) {
   return object_instance($obj);
}
       
$x = new stdClass();
echo $this->getInstance($x);
```

**Expected output would be:**

```
stdClass
```

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks @Catcon below who suggested:
[I think this is what you want: stackoverflow.com/questions/15103810/… – catcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103810/how-do-i-get-class-name-in-php)

The answer is actually this:

```
$x = new stdClass();
echo get_class($x);
```

Comment: An object is already an instance of a class. There is no such thing as an instance of an object.

Comment: syntax corrected to: the 'instanceof' an object

Comment: I think this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103810/how-do-i-get-class-name-in-php

Comment: thanks but I do not see something on that page. working example?

Comment: i see it now. get_class($x)
type your answer and i will accept it.