# InstanceOf Object Inheritance

Tags: php, class, inheritance

Is it possible to determine whether an object is of a specific class, rather than whether an object is a parent class or that class? i.e. only return true if its that specific class, and false if it is the parent class.

For example:

```php
class ExampleClass {
    ...
}

class ExampleClassExtension extends ExampleClass {
    ...
}

$a = new ExampleClass();
$b = new ExampleClassExtension();

var_dump($b instanceof ExampleClass) //Returns true as ExampleClassExtension is inherited from ExampleClass although I would like it to return false.
```

Is there any way to ignore the inheritance and check whether an object is specifically that class and return false if it is the parent class or child class or just any class that **isn't** the specific class I'm checking for?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible no. If you are writing an `if` to determine multiple type you would need to start with the child class `if ($foo instanceof ExampleClassExtension) { ... }elseif($foo instanceof ExampleClass) { ... }` or use `get_class`

Comment: What is the use case whereby you want to know if it's the parent class specifically? Please edit the question to clarify, this sounds like an https://xyproblem.info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get class name in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103810/how-do-i-get-class-name-in-php) - you can use something like `get_class($b) === ExampleClass::class)` with the code in the question.

Comment: @AD7six I don't want to check if its the parent class specifically, I want to check if it is a class specifically, regardless of inheritance. I want a child class to return false checking against the parent class rather than true as it currently does.

Comment: Thank you. I believe a combination of the above, using ExampleClass::class and order of ``if`` statements to be the correct solution.

Comment: `@AD7six ..., I want to check if it is a class specifically, regardless of inheritance.` - thats exactly the same as what I asked :), but you haven't said why. Again:  Please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically check if a class is equal to a certain class, you can use reflection

```php
<?php

class ExampleClass {
    public const A = 'a';
}

class ExampleClassExtension extends ExampleClass {
    public const B = 'b';
}

$a = new ExampleClass();
$b = new ExampleClassExtension();

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($b);
var_dump($reflectionClass->getName() === ExampleClass::class);
```