# How to get name of class without instantiating it?

Tags: php, pdo

In C# I can write the following with the [`nameof` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) to get a string that contains "MyClass":

```cs
var name = nameof(MyClass);
```

I.e. I can fill a string variable with the name of a class.

What I'm currently looking for is to get something similar in **PHP**.

I figured out the this does *not* compile:

```php
$name = get_class(MyClass)
```

This one does compile and correctly puts the string "MyClass" in `$name`:

```php
$name = get_class(new MyClass())
```

What bothers me on this is that I have to instantiate the class.

#### My question

Is it possible the get the name of a class in PHP without instantiating it?

#### Background information

The reason I'm looking for this functionality is that I'm trying to use the [`fetchObject` PDO method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) and would like to avoid hard-coding the class name (first parameter to the method call).

Comment: OMG, you beat me. Could you post this as an answer, then I can delete mine and give you the points.

Comment: I'm just going to flag it as a duplicate

Comment: Just so you know, there is zero lookup for validity, it is blind. You can see an example here: https://3v4l.org/m6l5Z

Comment: @ChrisHaas Wow, that's bad (I guess). Being 90% C# developer I'm constantly shocked about PHP. How on earth could all those reviewers of the language let such an error-prone behavior slip into the language? I honestly cannot understand.

Comment: It has to do with loading which could be expensive, especially when this feature was created in 2012. Also, it is possible it doesn't exist, but a middleware might want to transport it because it is just a string. If you really wanted, you could read the [discussion on it](https://externals.io/message/59931). However, if you have a need for it, you could pair this with [`class_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) which has an option to follow the autoload or just look for previously declared.

Comment: Here's a very fictional example however you can find some similar examples in real-world code: https://3v4l.org/Zf0Ep

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. Your kindness and your knowledge is mind-blowing to me 

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out:

```php
$name = MyClass::class
```

does the trick.

([See also a similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15103810/107625))