# Call method recursively through class hierarchy

Tags: php, oop

I want to call recursively the parent methods :

```
<?php
class generation1 {
    public function whoami() {
        echo get_class($this).PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function awesome() { // stop recursion
        $this->whoami();
    }
}

class generation2 extends generation1 {
    public function awesome() {
        $this->whoami();
        parent::awesome();
    }
}

class generation3 extends generation2 {}
class generation4 extends generation3 {}

$gen = new generation4();
$gen->awesome();
```

The output is :

> generation4
>
> generation4

I would like to have :

> generation4
>
> generation3
>
> generation2
>
> generation1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__CLASS__` magic constant is not interpreted as being whatever the concrete class an instance *is*, but instead evaluates to the class name that the constant is *contained* in.

If you want to get the concrete class name (rather than the base class name), try using [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) instead.

```
<?php 

class A
{
    public function test1()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . "\n";
    }

    public function test2()
    {
        echo get_class($this) . "\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {}

$b = new B;

$b->test1();
$b->test2();
```

Output:

> A
>
> B

**Update**

In your particular situation, there are only *two* `awesome` methods; one defined on `generation2` and one defined on `generation1`.  `generation3` and `generation4` rely on their ancestor's definitions, and thus are not actually called inside of their context (this is why you only see *two* outputs, there's only two methods called).

You could get around this by defining the `awesome` method at every level like you have it written.  The trouble then is the `$this->whoami()` line.  `$this` in each of those contexts is referring to a concrete instance of a `generation4` object, so even at the `generation2` level calling `$this->whoami()` inside of the awesome method will cause the method on `generation4` to be called from all of the `awesome` methods.

You can get around this limitation, too, by changing `$this` to be `self`.  The final solution which I was able to come up with is this:

```
class gen1
{
    public function whoami()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function awesome()
    {
        self::whoami();
    }
}

class gen2 extends gen1 {
    public function whoami()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function awesome()
    {
        self::whoami();
        parent::awesome();
    }
}
class gen3 extends gen2 {
    public function whoami()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function awesome()
    {
        self::whoami();
        parent::awesome();
    }
}
class gen4 extends gen3 {
    public function whoami()
    {
        echo __CLASS__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function awesome()
    {
        self::whoami();
        parent::awesome();
    }
}

$gen4 = new gen4;
$gen4->awesome();
```

Which gives an output of:

> gen4
>
> gen3
>
> gen2
>
> gen1

You may be able to get around some of these limitations *if* you have PHP 5.5 installed (I am only on 5.4 locally right now, can't test this), but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694818/697370) for some other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question, the problem is still here.

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide an override for the `whoami` method at every level, and stick to using `__CLASS__` in order to get the output you want

Comment: Basically, the problem is why it doesn't display `generationX` 4 times ?