# How to get the name of child class from base class when an object of child class is created

Tags: php, oop

I want to get the name of my child class in the base class so that whenever an object of child class is created I get the name of the child class in my base class. Something like this:

```
class Base_class {
    function __construct() {
        // Some code Here to get the name of the child class
    }
}

class Child_class extends Base_Class {}

class Another_child_class extends Base_Class {}

$object = new Child_Class;
$object2 = new Another_child_class;
```

When the `$object` is created I want the constructor to give me the name of the class from which the object was created.

Comment: This looks like the function you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Comment: my mistake.. i actually want the name of the child class in the constructor.

Comment: What actually you need within output

Comment: Smells like bad design, could you please provide a concrete use case?

Comment: i want the name of the child class of which the object has been created.

Comment: Superclasses should not be aware of their extensions. If you need to make decisions based on the class type, consider using a Factory.

Comment: I am working on codeigniter and i have a MY_Model class which will be extended by all the other Models. So i have decided to name my models same as that of the table name in the database. So I want that when i create a model and by only extending the MY_Model  class i want the name of the child model so i can get its associated table from database and perform desired query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the classname from a static call in an extended PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/how-can-i-get-the-classname-from-a-static-call-in-an-extended-php-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_class()` passing it the current object reference, like so:

```
class Base_class {

    function __construct() {
        $calledClassName = get_class($this);
    }

}
```

Edit: You can find more info on `get_class()` in the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Comment: my mistake.. i actually want the name of the child class in the constructor so i do not need to make any other calls from outside.

Comment: this outputs the name of the base class

Comment: Nope. This works fine, but @moonwave99 is right, it's a bit of a code smell.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, to an extent. In PHP 5.5, the [`::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) class constant was added, which returns the class name of class to which it is applied. You can then use this in conjunction with `parent`, `self`, or `static`. Consider this code:

```
<?php

class A {}

class B extends A
{
    public function foo() {
        echo parent::class . "\n";    // A
        echo __CLASS__ . "\n";        // B
        echo self::class . "\n";      // B
        echo static::class . "\n";    // D
        echo get_class($this) . "\n"; // D
    }
}

class C extends B {}
class D extends C {}

(new D)->foo();
```

`self::class` will return the same thing as `__CLASS__`, the class belonging to the function currently executing (in this case, `B`).

`parent::class` will return the name of the method's parent class (`A`).

`static::class`, by way of [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), will return the class name of the method that was actually invoked (`D`).

Note, however, that you can not get the immediate child descendent of your current function (`C`) without using more advanced means (parsing the call stack via `debug_backtrace`, or via reflection).

Answer (score 5):

This is certainly possible using `static::class` (*or `get_class($this)` or `get_called_class()`*) in the base class to get the name of the child (*which is initially called at runtime*):

```
<?php

class Foo 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(static::class, get_class($this), get_called_class());
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo { }

class Baz extends Bar { }

new Foo();
new Bar();
new Baz();
```

Produces:

```
string(3) "Foo"
string(3) "Foo"
string(3) "Foo"
string(3) "Bar"
string(3) "Bar"
string(3) "Bar"
string(3) "Baz"
string(3) "Baz"
string(3) "Baz"
```

This is called [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). Here's a [demo](https://eval.in/515805) of the above.

Comment: `get_called_class()` for anyone needing 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just pass it explicitly then:

```
class BaseClass{

  function __construct($tableName){
    // do stuff w/ $tableName
  }

}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass{

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct('ChildClass');
  }

}
```

Comment: Have an upvote, your approach is the most sensible and shouldn't have been downvoted.

Comment: Because hardcoding the class name is a pretty crappy "solution".